# "A Task was Canceled" running async JS on several concurrent offscreen browsers

Tags: javascript, c#, asynchronous, task, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp.OffScreen (C#) with Cef Package version 89.0.170.0.

I'm running 8 offscreen browsers concurrently to capture and render some web pages but 7 of them throw a "Task canceled" exception when I try and run some async JS execution task at the beginning of the capture, as if only one of them was capable of running JS while the others wait for their turn and fail miserably.

Here is the code I'm using to execute some JS:

```
JavascriptResponse  result = await browser.MainFrame.EvaluateScriptAsync( "some JS code", timeout:TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 1000 ) );
```

I tried putting some delay between each browser's capture job and it seems to be faring a little better, but it's still dependent on the time it takes each browser to execute the scripts and continues to fail for some browsers. I don't like this method as it's not very reliable anyway.

Overall, despite the fact I have 8 different browser instances, it looks like there's only one JS execution engine running and stalling the other browsers.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to make the browsers wait longer before canceling the task? What makes them even cancel the task in the first place?

Best regards.

Comment: What framework are you using? What is `browser.MainFrame.EvaluateScriptAsync`? What even is that language?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of context. I edited my question.

Comment: Each browser has it's own V8Context, depending on the url origin they maybe sharing the same render process. Please edit your original question and provide a more detailed example,  a single line of code out of context doesn't say much.